# How can I convert a javascript array to json format to serve as the response from a REST api

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
I am trying to figure out how to take an array of arrays and convert it to a json string to return via a REST api.

My server gets records from a database. Each record is in the form:

    {"user":"some name","age":number}
```

I need to return the data in json format so that the REST specification is valid.
Sometimes I get a single record to return other times I get multiple records.
Below is a sample script I am using to test the syntax for converting into json format.

```
var resultSet = [];
resultSet.push({"user":"John Doe","age":43});
resultSet.push({"user":"Jane doe","age":29});
var myJson = JSON.parse(resultSet);
```

When I run this code using nodejs I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: `resultSet` is not JSON. Please be aware that a JS object/array is not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

[`JSON.parse`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) expects a string. You are passing an Array.

This works because the input is a string:

```js
JSON.parse('[{"foo": "bar"}]')
```

This doesn't work because the input is an Array:

```js
JSON.parse([{"foo": "bar"}])
```

Are you trying to return an Array or a string? If you are trying to return a string, then you should use [`JSON.stringify`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) like this:

```js
JSON.stringify([{"foo": "bar"}])
```